# What are the benefits of installing node, react-native, npm and expo do your desktop when you can just code in expo snack?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Installing node, react-native and all the required packages and software on your desktop is fairly tedious. What are the benefits of doing that over using expo snack instead?

Comment: 1. *You* are in control of your source code, not anybody else. 2. You are in control of your environment, too. 3. You are in control of build steps, what tools to use and so on.

Comment: And is installing all this *really* that tedious? I seriously haven't tried this particular stack but usually you install Node *once* and you are set for any stack you'll use. Then just run few `npm install`s and you're set for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit by far is that you can integrate with native modules. With expo you cannot.